# pyOpenSSL: wrong protocol version for the connection

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl

Environment:

Python 3.7 (Anaconda 5.3.1 on Windows)
pyOpenSSL 18.0
SSL.SSLEAY_VERSION: OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018

I have a socket, which is used for some unencrypted communication and then is wrapped by pyOpenSSL:

```
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((address, port))
sock.send(msg)

context = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD)
conn = SSL.Connection(context, sock)
conn.set_connect_state()
conn.do_handshake()
```

I expect the protocol to be TLS 1.2, which is specified for the context object, but Wireshark shows the following:

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 302
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 298
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
```

And I get:

```
Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_RECORD', 'wrong version number')]
```

I suppose the error has something to do with the fact that TLS 1.0 is used, but I don't understand where does it come from? If I check `conn.get_protocol_version_name()`, it shows `TLSv1.2`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I am going to answer the question myself. `TLS 1.0 (0x0301)` in the record layer of a ClientHello message is [expected](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/1689) in OpenSSL.

I got `wrong version number` because the request was not routed correctly on the server side, so the response was not a valid ServerHello message.